# How to reorder a CSV's rows based on order of appearance of unique values with bash/unix tools?

Tags: bash, sorting, command-line, unix

I've used Python to parse a large test result file of flight data, but need to reorder its rows by grouping the same values together, in order of appearance.

The CSV is currently ordered:

```
 (Flight ID)                  (Trajectory Data)
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,42  (Time 0)                               
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,54  (Time 0)                               
20110117559574, , , , , , , , ,2391,6284,390,54  (Time 0)                               
20110117559587, , , , , , , , ,2385,6273,390,54  (Time 0)                               
20110117559588, , , , , , , , ,2816,6847,250,32  (Time 0) 
...
```

where every unique ID is listed with its current trajectory data at one point in time.  This order then repeats with new trajectory data for every minute these flight are in the air.

The way I need it reordered is:

```
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,42  (Time 0)
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,42  (Time 1)
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,42  (Time 2)
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,42  (Time 3)
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,42  (Time N)
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,54  (Time 0)
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,54  (Time 1)
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,54  (Time 2)
... and so on
```

I've written another Python script to handle this job, but because of the large file size, it takes 3-4 hours.  I would like to find the way of doing this with bash/unix tools, which I am unfamiliar with in this context, and was looking at something along the lines of the sort utility:

```
sort -n -s -t, -k1,1 infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

-t sets the delimiter, -k sets the sort key, -s stabilizes the sort, and -n uses numeric comparison.

Any ideas?  (I'll look to add rep if you can use a one-liner).

**Clarification:**
I want all the details for the first flight that appears in the input data file grouped together at the start of the output file; then you want all the details for the second flight number that appears in the input file grouped together next, and repeat ad nauseam. – Jonathan Leffler

Comment: How large is the file? Feel like posting your python code? No problem doing this using e.g. awk but you'll need to buffer an awful lot of lines. Python is probably easier to optimize...

Comment: 68MB, 1.3 million some rows.  I've posted about optimizing my Python code before, finding I really just needed to tell my laptop to quit going to sleep.  Here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148983/looking-for-a-more-efficient-way-to-reorganize-a-massive-csv-in-python

Comment: (This question is based on one of the answers to that question)

Comment: What's wrong with the `sort` command you offered?  Are the times really parenthesized as an extra part of the last field of the trajectory?  Are there really lots of blank spaces between the commas?

Comment: It orders the file in order of least to greatest Flight ID, I'm looking for the correct parameters to use, or a similar method.  No, those aren't really there.

Comment: Just did some benchmarking with sort vs awk on a 200k-line test-file. sort finishes in 2s while awk needs minutes. As the mighty Jonathan Leffler says, whats wrong with sort?

Comment: I need order of appearance while reading in descending order, rather than least to greatest.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want all the details for the first flight that appears in the input data file grouped together at the start of the output file; then you want all the details for the second flight number that appears in the input file grouped together next, and repeat ad nauseam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to preprocess the file to impose an ordering, sort it using the imposed ordering, and then remove the ordering information.  The `awk` script has spaces removed so it fits on one line in SO without the horizontal scroll bar — it hurt to remove the spaces.

```
awk -F, '{if(order[$1]==0)order[$1]=++counter;print order[$1]","$0;}' infile.csv |
sort -t, -s -k1,1n |
sed 's/^[^,]*,//'
```

This looks to see whether the flight number (field `$1`) has been seen before.  If not, it is allocated a new sequential number.  The record is then output with the sequential number at the start of the line, followed by a comma and the original record.  The output is sorted stably (it would be possible to modify the `awk` so that you got stable sorting even if the `sort` program did not support that).  Then the sorted output has the sequential number removed; I chose to use `sed` but `cut` or `awk` or a number of other programs could be used instead.

I tested with the input file shown below, which is based on the data in the question, but I've reordered things so that the file '587 and '588 appear before '572 in the input (so it is a more acid test of the sorting) and I also made each line unique by setting the last digit in the fourth trajectory column to a distinct value for each record (but the values were in descending order so that if the sort was working on the data, it would be out of order).

```
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,42
20110117559587, , , , , , , , ,2385,6273,390,54
20110117559588, , , , , , , , ,2816,6847,250,32
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,54
20110117559574, , , , , , , , ,2391,6284,390,54
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,49
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,48
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,59
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,47
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,46
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,45
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,58
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,57
```

This output looks correct to me:

```
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,42
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,49
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,48
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,2446,6720,370,47
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,46
20110117559515, , , , , , , , ,24xx,67xx,3xx,45
20110117559587, , , , , , , , ,2385,6273,390,54
20110117559588, , , , , , , , ,2816,6847,250,32
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,54
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,59
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,58
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,23xx,62xx,4xx,57
20110117559574, , , , , , , , ,2391,6284,390,54
```

You could probably do the whole thing in Perl fairly fast, too.  66 MiB is hardly an exorbitant amount of data to keep in memory in a machine that has one or more GiB of RAM.

This Perl script (genflights.pl) creates about 69 MiB of data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq = 1000000;

for my $time (0..1500)
{
    for my $flight (0..1000)
    {
        my $r0 = int(rand(1000)) + 20110117559000;
        my $r1 = int(rand(10000));
        my $r2 = int(rand(10000));
        my $r3 = int(rand(1000));
        my $r4 = int(rand(100));
        printf "%s, , ,%07d, ,%04d,%04d,%03d,%02d\n", $r0, ++$seq, $r1, $r2, $r3, $r4;
    }
}
```

The first few lines of output from one run were:

```
20110117559486, , ,1000001, ,2670,6847,792,91
20110117559489, , ,1000002, ,0278,1929,972,25
20110117559845, , ,1000003, ,9169,4915,145,21
20110117559356, , ,1000004, ,3519,1660,106,97
20110117559976, , ,1000005, ,8988,7830,884,64
20110117559446, , ,1000006, ,7459,7458,791,93
20110117559442, , ,1000007, ,7265,5853,012,41
20110117559686, , ,1000008, ,4624,0682,859,32
20110117559081, , ,1000009, ,3624,0264,017,06
20110117559336, , ,1000010, ,6501,9033,329,33
20110117559869, , ,1000011, ,5020,3008,919,96
20110117559047, , ,1000012, ,5747,4140,693,83
20110117559531, , ,1000013, ,0591,1866,482,68
20110117559355, , ,1000014, ,2254,2731,946,99
20110117559952, , ,1000015, ,0941,0531,743,85
```

It took about 3 seconds to generate 69 MiB (file `flights`). I then ran the script above (with the output redirected to a file `flights.out`) under 'time' and got the output:

```
+ awk -F, '{if(order[$1]==0)order[$1]=++counter;print order[$1]","$0;}' flights
+ sort -t, -s -k1,1n
+ sed 's/^[^,]*,//'

real    0m8.658s
user    0m7.881s
sys     0m0.441s
```

Under 10 seconds for the processing of 69 MiB.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  69115046 Mar 13 09:04 flights
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  69115046 Mar 13 09:06 flights.out
```

The output file started:

```
20110117559486, , ,1000001, ,2670,6847,792,91
20110117559486, , ,1001621, ,2274,5287,188,57
20110117559486, , ,1001642, ,2716,6983,778,49
20110117559486, , ,1002791, ,1704,9426,430,05
...
20110117559486, , ,2501369, ,4900,8239,048,70
20110117559486, , ,2501850, ,7114,8721,684,40
20110117559489, , ,1000002, ,0278,1929,972,25
20110117559489, , ,1000090, ,0114,7462,862,55
20110117559489, , ,1000904, ,7780,8559,121,47
20110117559489, , ,1001499, ,9320,8459,592,01
...
20110117559489, , ,2499635, ,5199,8313,668,30
20110117559489, , ,2499955, ,3386,6280,102,19
20110117559489, , ,2500748, ,5740,6370,594,15
20110117559489, , ,2501534, ,1222,9866,714,24
20110117559845, , ,1000003, ,9169,4915,145,21
20110117559845, , ,1000220, ,5341,8347,724,25
20110117559845, , ,1000295, ,5722,4031,045,11
...
```

This is running on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro, 16 GiB RAM, Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: This returned least to greatest again for me, I used exact code shown.  There are 16,000 some unique Flight ID's, the 4th value represents the altitude, I would not change/use that or any of the other values for reference.

Comment: What do you get on the sample data set (the tiny one)?  The same output as mine, or a different output?  Is the output I showed the output you would expect for the input data I showed?

Comment: That requires sign-up...can you place somewhere that doesn't require that?

Comment: Sorry about that, try this.  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6cj8n7r7pbvzmu/newtrajectory.csv)

Comment: OK; I'm downloading, but in the first 16000 lines of your data, there are only 2 flight numbers that are not in ascending sequence.  Are you castigating us for doing what your data dictates that we do?

(`sed 16000q newtrajectory.csv | awk -F, '{ if (old != 0 && $1 < old) print old, $1; old = $1; }'` yields two lines of output: `20110117614463 20110117559423` and `20110117614499 20110117559423`.)  So, the data will very largely be presented in numeric order simply because the input data is very largely sorted in numeric order.

Comment: Interesting, I did not catch that.  I was making an assumption when I said it wasn't.  The input file I made for NASA's FACET software wasn't in order, I guess once it completes the simulation, the test results file it spits out (a messy text file) is in order, weird.  Thank you for verifying that, hopefully those values won't skew anything.

Comment: In the full file, there are 672 pairs of lines where the old and new flights are out order.  So, I believe that you are simply seeing an artefact of the data you supplied.  Have you tried editing the file and moving a few lines from somewhere around line 1000 (say 20 of them) up to the top of the file.  You can then check that those flights appear first in the output.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you.  I'll go ahead and give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a ids
declare -A flights
i=0
while IFS= read -r line;
do
   id=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)
   if [[ -z ${flights[$id]} ]]; then
       flights[$id]=$line
       ids[$i]=$id
       i=$((i+1))
   else
       flights[$id]=${flights[$id]}$'\n'$line
   fi  
done < infile.csv
for id in "${ids[@]}"
do
    echo "${flights[$id]}"
done > outfile.csv
```

This uses an associative array `flights` to build a string containing all the info for each flight. Also, it uses a normal array `ids` that keeps track of the order in which flights appear in the file.

To output, we just iterate through the `ids` array and keep printing the strings from `flights` array.

This doesn't try to do any kind of sorting and also reads through the file only once.

Comment: Line 3 "-A" flag gave me some errors, fixed that, now it's humming away.  Any idea of the speed of this script?  It's handling 1.3 million rows.

Comment: What was the error. I checked the script on a small input. `-A` is for associative arrays in bash. I think its only available in bash version 4. No idea of speed :)

Comment: 68MB file, it seems to be storing 1MB every 70 seconds.  If it works at least it's faster than my Python solution.

Comment: Error was:

line 3: declare: -A: invalid option \
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: I guess your bash version is old. Like I said, associative arrays are only available in bash version 4. This script won't work for you then.

Comment: I'll update after this run, or use one of my VM's and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Totally different approach

```
awk -F',' '{print $0 >> $1;close($1)}' ~/Downloads/newtrajectory.csv
```

Need to use `close()` on the file, since there are to many to keep them all open.

The awk-script above will output as many files as there are unique Flight IDs

i.e, the file `20110117559515` will contain all items for that id and so on.

Its almost as  fast as the `sort` approach, ~5s for a 200k-lines test file.

As a post-process-step, use `cat` and a for-loop to concatenate everything into a single file.

To get the first unique ids:

```
NR>1{
  a[$1]+=1
  if (a[$1] == 2) {
    exit
  }
  else {
    print $1
  }
}
```

Then you can use a simple while-loop to concatenate everyting

```
 while read line; do cat $line >> final.csv; done < cnt.txt
```

output:

```
$ head final.csv 
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2390,6274,410,54
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2391,6268,410,101
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2392,6261,410,144
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2394,6254,410,183
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2395,6247,410,219
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2397,6240,410,251
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2399,6232,410,279
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2400,6223,410,304
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2402,6215,410,326
20110117559572, , , , , , , , ,2404,6207,410,347
```

which looks ok to me.

Some timings:

```
$ time awk -F',' '{print $0 >> $1;close($1)}' ~/Downloads/newtrajectory.csv

real    0m14.534s
user    0m4.096s
sys     0m10.101s

$ time awk -F',' -f u.awk ~/Downloads/newtrajectory.csv > cnt.txt

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s

$ time while read line; do cat $line >> final.csv; done < cnt.txt 

real    0m4.282s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m1.028s
```

Comment: How do you arrange to concatenate the files in the correct sequence?

Comment: one way might be to use `sort | uniq` to get the number of well, unique flight-ids and then extract that amount of lines from the orignal file since that one was ordered, i.e. `sed '2,Xp'` and then loop over that list